# Write to file object id and value then read it

Tags: android-studio, filereader, filewriter

how to write in android local file:
object text and its id (for many objects) and after that how to correctly read them, so I put the correct text to correct object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use database SQLite insert there your text object and its id and then read them by cursor if id will be correct for each row set text.